# Is the ending of Thief (2014) fixed regardless of player actions?

Tags: thief

Earlier this year, I finished Thief(2014), after judicious use of cheating to give me extra of everything. Because I had so many arrows etc, I ended up just shooting all of the enemies with lethal arrows.

The game had a real downer ending,

> with many major characters dying, including the Baron and the girl.

. I wonder if this ending was caused by all the murder and mayhem I caused. Does the game have multiple endings, or is the ending always the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thief/comments/1za3br/are_there_multiple_endings/), **there is just one ending**, so, no, your play style and/or choices do not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one ending, but the girl lives. The claw is back in a wooden post next to Garret. Defying physics, he hurled the claw so hard that it caught up to Erin and she caught it then climbed up, otherwise the claw would be lost in the ocean.

Comment: That makes so much of sense now that you say it. I wondered why the claw was back in the post. Leaves the option open for Erin in a potential sequel.